# Принять POST в PHP. Функция file_get_contents("php://input") возвращает пустую строку, если Content-Length мимо

Tags: php, post, авторизация, клиент-сервер, file-get-contents

Я пытаюсь отловить запрос POST при помощи PHP:

```
<?php
    require "../db.php";

    $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $requestBody = json_decode($data, true);
    $login = $requestBody['login'];
    $password = $requestBody['password'];

    $user = R::findOne('users', 'login = ?', array($login));
    if($user)
    {
        if(password_verify($password, $user->password))
        {
            $d = array('access'=>true, 'comment'=>'Auhorization successful!');
        }
        else
        {
            $d = array('access'=>false, 'comment'=>'Incorrect password!'); 
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        $d = array('access'=>false, 'comment'=>'User '.$login.' not found!');
    }
    echo json_encode($d);
?>
```

Единственный удачный результат даёт client.restlet.com, когда я указываю (вернее автоматически указывается) Header Content-Length:

[image: Отправка запроса в client.restlet.com]

Если указывается число меньше 55, то приходит обусловленный кодом PHP следующий JSON:

```
{"access":false,"comment":"User  not found!"}
```

А если число больше 55, то запрос зависает.

Поведение приложения Postman в этой ситуации: Сообщение "User  not found!" возвращается при числе менее или равном 37, на 38 запрос зависает, а положительный ответ вообще не даётся.

Пытаюсь послать запрос в Android Studio через Retrofit2 (не буду приводить весь код, он тривиален, ограничусь только кодом ApiService:

```
import com.hand.tubes.model.AuthorizationResponse;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.POST;
import retrofit2.http.Query;
import retrofit2.http.Headers;

public interface ApiService {
    @Headers({
            "Content-Type: application/json",
            "Content-Length: 80"
    })
    @POST("auth")
    Call<AuthorizationResponse> authorize(
            @Query("login") String login,
            @Query("password") String password);
}
```

Так тут вообще интересное кино, ему и 90 - мало (то есть приходит "User  not found!", как и в других случаях с двумя пробелами между User и not, там где должен стоять логин, т.е. параметры из тела запроса где-то теряются)

До этого пытался отловить тело запроса при помощи переменной $_POST - но она тоже приходила пустой.

Помогите решить проблему. Немного эмоций: честно говоря вообще считаю это полным маразмом указывать длину запроса, учитывая также то, что она каждый раз разная, а в Retrofite ковыряться в Header'ах, указывая варьирующую длину, не очень-то удобно. В идеале: как мне исправить (или вообще переписать) файл PHP, чтобы в запросе Content-Length вообще не указывать. Раньше я писал клиентскую часть авторизации, никакого Content-Length не указывал - и всё работало на ура. Жалею, что тогда не посмотрел обрабатывающий запрос PHP файл. Сейчас попытался скачать это файл с сервера - так он переехал, а куда - непонятно. Буду благодарен, если кто-нибудь даст ссылки на правильные PHP, принимающие POST запросы такого рода - может быть это вообще не при помощи file_get_contents("php://input") делается, а как-то по другому.

Comment: Если хотите удалить вопрос - просто удалите, не стоит вместо этого заменять текст на lknlknsdvzkngfj

Comment: @PashaPash, я хочу поднять вопрос наверх. Я задал его ночью, он спустился вниз и теперь у него низкая проходимость

Comment: Ну так добавьте в него информации по существу. А то на вашу правку начали прилетать флаги "спам" с автоминусами, пару таких флагов - и ваш вопрос вообще никто не увидит.

Comment: @PashaPash, в нём что, по-вашему, мало информации по существу? Конкретный код, скриншот, и конкретное изложение проблемы

Comment: Ну тогда ждите ответа - механизма апа на сайте нет :(

Comment: @PashaPash а если попробовать удалить, а потом перезадать тот же вопрос, через какое время перестанет выскакивать сообщение, что текст дублируется?

Comment: Если вы попробуете удалить и пересоздать несколько раз - то система вас забанит, а потом придет модератор и скажет, что так делать не стоит.

Comment: @ПавелСумароков Для апа вопроса просто внесите правку. Даже в самом вроде до  идеала "заточеном" сообщении найдутся опечатки/неточности/размытые формулировки. Стоит учесть, что частый ап с незначительной правкой, например, каждые пол-часа пару букв менять, приведёт к минусам от "внимательных минусаторов".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Серверу нужно как-то узнать длину запроса, который вы ему посылаете. Узнавание длины строго задано в [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.3). Для запросов порядок получения длины тела такой:

1. Если используется Transfer-Encoding/chunked - то используется длина из конкретных чанков (явно не ваш случай)
2. Используется Content-Length.
3. Если Content-Length нет - тело считается пустым.

В вашем случае (2) сервер вычитывает из сокета ровно столько, сколько пришло в Content-Length.

Если пришло меньше - он сидит и ждет, пока придет еще ("зависает")

Если пришло больше - он просто обрезает по Content Length.

Почти все высокоуровневые библиотеки для вызова API сами высчитывают Content Length для отправляемых запросов. Низкоуровневые - требуют ручного задания длины.

Например, Postman сам дописывает Content Length, если его не задать явно. В интерфейсе хедера нет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А в реальном запросе есть:

```
POST http://ru.stackoverflow.com/ HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 0db86e7c-1649-41d4-98b9-19aebdbcf18e
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.3.0
Accept: */*
Host: ru.stackoverflow.com
cookie: prov=e712f6ff-bef2-3787-431c-03d858b78086
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
content-length: 10
Connection: keep-alive

test=value
```

Попробуйте убрать явное задание длины тела в том коде, где вы вызываете API.

Comment: Так а как мне внедрить Transfer-Encoding/chunked, если это, конечно, возможно? Я так полагаю, что это тот самый случай, когда я отправлял запрос на ранее созданный (не мною) сервер, и вообще не задавал Content-Length.

Comment: @ПавелСумароков нет, вам нужно разобраться, почему та библиотека, которую вы используете для отправки запроса, не добавляет Content-Length сама. Может быть достаточно будет его просто из явно заданных заголовков убрать?

Comment: @ПавелСумароков попробуйте удалить  "Content-Length: 80" из Headers - вдруг заработает?

Comment: Когда я в Postman'е не задаю Content-Length, приходит ответ, как будто задано 0 символов, то есть file_get_content функция выдаёт пустую строку. И странно - 36 символов мало, а 37 - много, что запрос содержит 36.5 символов?

Comment: @ПавелСумароков возьмите отладчик http (Fiddler) и посмотрите, что реально уходит

Comment: нет, опять облом: удалил Content-Length из Android Studio, но ответ всё равно приходит пустой. А с Fiddlerom пока только разбираюсь

Comment: В Fiddler'е (раздел Raw) следующее:

POST http://host1710566.hostland.pro/auth/ HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: host1710566.hostland.pro
Content-Length: 46

{"login":"PavelSumarokov","password":"123456"}

И ответ приходит правильный

Comment: @ПавелСумароков ну ок, значит проблема именно в парсинге ответа в коде java. Может быть с форматом AuthorizationResponse не угадали?

Comment: Ответ обрабатывается правильно, простите, неверно написал, не ответ приходит пустой, а в PHP функция file_get_contents("php://input") - пустая строка, и это видно по ответу

Comment: Вопрос заключается в следующем: как мне в модуле PHP получить тело запроса, если Content-Length не указано в заголовке. Я так понял, что Fiddler автоматически ставит Content-Length, но Retrofit2 в Android Studio -то это не делает, а нужно именно в мобильном приложении отправлять запрос в конечном итоге

Comment: @ПавелСумароков ответ - никак, это часть HTTP протокола. Если Content-Length не задан - значит, запрос считается пустым. Я уверен, что Retrofit2 это делает - иначе бы у всех, кто им пользовался, не работали бы POST-запросы. Если у вас при конкретном запросе Content-Length не уходит - приведите минимальный пример для воспроизведения проблемы - который можно было бы скопировать, запустить - и увидеть что тело запроса ушло, а content-length - нет. лучше в виде отдельного вопроса.

Comment: Пробую отладить запрос через Retrofit. Но ещё раз добавлю, что ранее я отправлял запрос POST на другой сервер, и в Header'ах указывал то же самое, Content-Length не прописывал, во всяком случае вручную. И ответ приходил. Я к тому, что может быть это не в клиенте, а на сервере прописывать нужно вычисление Content-Length, и если да, то каким образом?

Comment: @ПавелСумароков нет,  вычисление Content-Length должно быть на клиенте. 100%. вот, там выше ссылка на RFC.

Comment: В Postman'е странная особенность. Я модифицировал ответ, вставив echo file_get_contents("php://input"). Осознанное сокращение Content-Length в client.restlet.com выдает урезанное тело запроса. А когда отправляю через Postman, и устанавливаю заведомо короткое значение Content-Length, фрагмент тела запроса не отображается, то есть Content-Length в Postman'е вообще ни автоматически, ни вручную не устанавливается.

Выглядит это так:

https://vk.com/id27696843?z=photo27696843_456239458%2Falbum27696843_00%2Frev

https://vk.com/id27696843?z=photo27696843_456239459%2Falbum27696843_00%2Frev